# How to exclude files from TAR archive using regular expressions?

Tags: linux, tar, regex, archive

I have a simple question, yet I can't find or solve the answer. I want to make a tar archive, but I want to exclude some files from it using regular expression.

Example of the file to exclude is this: `68x640X480.jpg`

I have tried this with no luck:

```
tar cvf test.tar --exclude=[0-9]+x[0-9X]+\.jpg /data/foto
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use some additional tools like `find` and `egrep`:

```
find directory/ -type f -print | egrep -v '[0-9]+x[0-9X]+\.jpg' | tar cvfz directory.tar.gz -T -
```

The drawback of the above mentioned method is that it will not work for all possible file names. Another opportunity is to use the built-in exclude functionality of `tar`:

```
tar -czvf directory.tar.gz --exclude='*x*X*.jpg' directory
```

Unfortunately the second method does not work with regular expressions, but only with wildcards.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Can you please make a note about what file names wouldn't work ? e.g. containing what characters ?

Comment: You shouldn't worry too much about that - most file names work perfectly fine with that solution. The problem is that UNIX/Linux file names can include pretty much everything, even control characters - such obscure combinations will not work with the first solution.

Comment: A nice read related to UNIX/Linux/POSIX file names: http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html

Comment: What does the "-T -" at the end do?

Comment: @MBasith the `-T` option enables `tar` to read the files to archive from another file (`--files-from=FILE`). The `-` (dash) refers in this case to standard input. This is useful when the file list needs to be generated from another process and piped into `tar`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try **cpio**

https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html

It reads from file list and does the archiving. You can generate a file list using **sed** like given below.

```
ls |sed   '/[0-9]*x[0-9]*X.*/d' >/tmp/files
```

You can then use it as the input to cpio.